# Google Nest Hello (doorstation) integration into IOS Homekit possible?

Tags: ios, nest-api

Is there a way that I can integrate my Google Nest Hello Doorstation into my IOS Homekit?
The camera livestream and the bell signaling would be important.
If that is possible, where can I find instructions? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a NestHello and NestThermostat V3  and a I'm on Apple Homekit with HOOBS. For Nest I use this plugin https://github.com/chrisjshull/homebridge-nest for HOMEBIRDGE/HOOBS.